# Error: INVALID_FIELD, Cannot specify both an external ID reference and a salesforce id

Tags: apex

Initially when a form is saved it inserts both parent and child object records in one DML Statement using parent external Id. later when same form is edited then it should insert as a form that is both parent and child saves as new record, at this point system is throwing following exception even after setting parent Id as 'Null'.

Insert failed. First exception on row 1; first error: INVALID_FIELD, Cannot specify both an external ID reference parent_Id__r and a salesforce id, parent_Id__c: []

Below is the method sets the parent Id as null.

```
 public static list<sobject> resetRecordIdsInList(list<sobject> sObjs){

        for(sobject s : sObjs){

            s.put('Id', Null);
            s.put('parent_Id__c',Null);
            s.putSObject('parent_ID__r', new parent__c(External_Id__c = ExternalId));
        }

         return sObjs; 
    }
```

Comment: Is parent_Id__c a lookup or an external ID field. Seems you are trying to assign an external ID field to a Lookup field..

Comment: Sorry, it is external Id field in parent object which i have updated in the post.

Comment: « When you edit the form » of an existing couple parent+child, are you sure you’re using update and not insert ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify both an ID (in this case, null), *and* an external ID (which presumably would generate a non-null value). Do not specify both `Parent_Id__c` and `Parent_Id__r` on the same record.

Comment: If i don't specify parent_Id__c  system is throwing same error because it is retaining parentId at the time of loading the prior version of the form.  Following  is the query to display version of previous submit. when i debug the results system also prints child id and also parentid in child record.      select Id,(select Name__c from child__r) from parent__c where id =: parentId. Next child records from query results are passed to the method mentioned in  main post.

Comment: I've observed that this behaviour is NOT reproducible when using inline DML keywords (such as `insert accountList`), however when using other syntax, including the inline user mode one, it is reproduced, seems like a bug that should fail or pass consistently independently of the syntax right?

Comment: @jonathanwiesel That's an interesting observation. I would imagine that they go through different code paths but should end up at the same point just before the database layer. They should have identical behavior. Reflecting on this, I think the better solution in this case would have been to clone the records to clear the fields, or perhaps some getPopulatedFieldsAsMap trickery, which wasn't available in 2015.